# VB.NET check if use has chosen one ofthe the drop-dwon options

Tags: vb.net

So I have a combobox and i wanted to validate it. I've got the presence check all done, now i just need to make sure that the user it only contains one of the drop-down options (instead of something they have typed in themselves). I've tried:

```
If Not combobox1.text.Equals("BookingID") And Not combobox1.text.Equals("Booking_date") Then
        errors.Enqueue("Please select a field to search by")
    End If
```

This results in me always getting the error message, whether i've selected one of the options or not.

Comment: How about set the dropdown style to DropDownList.

Comment: If your control was bound to a List(of Booking) you might also be able to perform a more positive test than just testing the Text

Comment: Thanks, that works. But just out of curiousity, why doesnt my code work?